# click show and hide search box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do it like in the video I uploaded below. That's what I've done for now, but when I click the search icon, I can't replace it with the x icon. I think I couldn't do this because I have little knowledge of Javascript. I would be very happy if you could help me with this.
https://files.fm/f/856dwf9kj

```js
function buttonUp(){
         var valux = $('.sb-search-input').val(); 
            valux = $.trim(valux).length;
            if(valux !== 0){
                $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','99');
            } else{
                $('.sb-search-input').val(''); 
                $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','-999');
            }
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var submitIcon = $('.sb-icon-search');
        var submitInput = $('.sb-search-input');
        var searchBox = $('.sb-search');
        var qutu = $('.qutu');
        var isOpen = false;
        
        $(document).mouseup(function(){
            if(isOpen == true){
            submitInput.val('');
            $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','-999');
            submitIcon.click();
            }
        });
        
        submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
            return false;
        });
        
        searchBox.mouseup(function(){
            return false;
        });
                
        submitIcon.click(function(){
            if(isOpen == false){
                searchBox.addClass('sb-search-open');
                qutu.removeClass('noborder');
                qutu.addClass('bborder');
                isOpen = true;
            } else {
                searchBox.removeClass('sb-search-open');
                qutu.removeClass('bborder');
                qutu.addClass('noborder');
                isOpen = false;
            }
    });

});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 40px 60px;
}
*{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     transition: all 0.5s;
}
form{
    display: inline-block;
}
.sb-search {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 0%;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.bborder{
    opacity: 1;
}
.noborder{
    opacity: 0;
}

.sb-search-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 20px 65px 20px 20px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2c3e50;
}
 
input[type="search"].sb-search-input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border:1px black solid;
}
.sb-search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
 
.sb-search-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
 
.sb-search-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
 
.sb-search-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

.sb-icon-search,
.sb-search-submit  {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sb-search-submit {
    background: #fff; /* IE needs this */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE 5-7 */
    opacity: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

.sb-icon-search {
    color: black;
    background: #fff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 0px;
    z-index: 90;
    margin: -5px;   
    top: 1px;
    right: 6px; 
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
 
.sb-icon-search:before {
    content: "";
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open,
.no-js .sb-search {
    width: 300px;
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-icon-search,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-icon-search {
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    z-index: 11;
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-search-submit,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-search-submit {
/*    z-index: 90;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Search bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search " >
    <form>
        <input class="sb-search-input qutu noborder" onkeyup="buttonUp();" placeholder="Enter your search term..." onblur="monkey();" type="search" value="" name="search" id="search">
        <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit"  value="">
        <span class="sb-icon-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? We need to know that, after all, you only post a question to StackOverflow if you have tried everything that you know and have searched up. Also, StackOverflow is here to help you fix a problem with code not give you the complete code to do something. The code that is given in an answer is to help fix the problem. So, this question is not really something that should be posted onto StackOverflow. 
To see if a question is on-topic or off-topic for StackOverflow go here: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new so I don't know enough about the forum. I will forward the codes to you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a really simple example below from the snippet you gave.
The only differences are inside the `submitIcon.click`.
You just have to do how you have done for your elements `searchBox` and `qutu` by adding/removing classes. Thanks to this, you will be able to change the FontAwesome icon you want to use for the element. It is probably perfectible, like by checking if the class exists before remove or add it (in a straight cae it should not, but we never know).

```js
function buttonUp(){
         var valux = $('.sb-search-input').val(); 
            valux = $.trim(valux).length;
            if(valux !== 0){
                $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','99');
            } else{
                $('.sb-search-input').val(''); 
                $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','-999');
            }
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var submitIcon = $('.sb-icon-search');
        var submitInput = $('.sb-search-input');
        var searchBox = $('.sb-search');
        var qutu = $('.qutu');
        var isOpen = false;
        
        $(document).mouseup(function(){
            if(isOpen == true){
            submitInput.val('');
            $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','-999');
            submitIcon.click();
            }
        });
        
        submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
            return false;
        });
        
        searchBox.mouseup(function(){
            return false;
        });
                
        submitIcon.click(function(){
            if(isOpen == false){
                searchBox.addClass('sb-search-open');
                qutu.removeClass('noborder');
                qutu.addClass('bborder');
                searchBox.find('i.fa').removeClass('fa-search');
                searchBox.find('i.fa').addClass('fa-times');
                isOpen = true;
            } else {
                searchBox.removeClass('sb-search-open');
                qutu.removeClass('bborder');
                qutu.addClass('noborder');
                searchBox.find('i.fa').removeClass('fa-times');
                searchBox.find('i.fa').addClass('fa-search');
                isOpen = false;
            }
    });

});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 40px 60px;
}
*{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     transition: all 0.5s;
}
form{
    display: inline-block;
}
.sb-search {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 0%;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.bborder{
    opacity: 1;
}
.noborder{
    opacity: 0;
}

.sb-search-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 20px 65px 20px 20px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2c3e50;
}
 
input[type="search"].sb-search-input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border:1px black solid;
}
.sb-search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
 
.sb-search-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
 
.sb-search-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
 
.sb-search-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

.sb-icon-search,
.sb-search-submit  {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sb-search-submit {
    background: #fff; /* IE needs this */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE 5-7 */
    opacity: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

.sb-icon-search {
    color: black;
    background: #fff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 0px;
    z-index: 90;
    margin: -5px;   
    top: 1px;
    right: 6px; 
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
 
.sb-icon-search:before {
    content: "";
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open,
.no-js .sb-search {
    width: 300px;
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-icon-search,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-icon-search {
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    z-index: 11;
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-search-submit,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-search-submit {
/*    z-index: 90;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Search bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search " >
    <form>
        <input class="sb-search-input qutu noborder" onkeyup="buttonUp();" placeholder="Enter your search term..." onblur="monkey();" type="search" value="" name="search" id="search">
        <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit"  value="">
        <span class="sb-icon-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This is exactly what I wanted. Have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome, please vote up for the answer then, and mark it as the "accepted answer" to show to others that the question is answered. Have a nice day!